# Android : How to avoid complete action using Dialog

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have made Qr code Scanner using Intent using Zxing library and i have kept Library in application so that my app no longer require barcode scanner. But When barcode scanner is already in operating system, when i start my application , a dialog box appear asking complete action using : barcode scanner or My application . When I have all library in my own application Then how can i avoid this Dialog Box. Please help me out.

Example code :

Intent in = new intent("com.google.zxing.android.SCAN");

Comment: What is the solution you used?

Answer (score 7):

To use:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setClassName("com.google.zxing.client.android", "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Or:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setClassName(this, "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: This shouldn't work, since `com.google.zxing.client.android` is our namespace (Barcode Scanner) and other apps most certainly should not be using it. This is why we strongly discourage copying our source directly.

Comment: The second one worked great for me as I wanted to avoid the "complete action using" dialog box. It works great now thx.

Comment: not working in S3, crash the app after inserting setClassName

Comment: Worked well for me, but I had to figure out what the class name and package names were (I used the first setClassName method).  That can be done with getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(...).

Answer (score 0):

Better still is to use the `IntentIntegrator` class provided by the project: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

This takes care of more cases (like the app not being installed) than just making your own `Intent`.